# Как преобразовать текст в dom элемент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я получаю из бд текст в таком формате

```html
<p>наливное водохранилище &ndash; часть каскадной системы водохранилищ, наряду с другим объектом &ndash; Коскорган.&nbsp;<br />Система нужна для накопления вод реки Кантаги (в некот источниках Карашык, средний многолетний сток реки 68 млн м3) в период многоводья.
  Так как объем водохранилища Коскорган позволяет вместить только 37 млн м3, то при его переполнении вода будет отводиться в кенсай-Коскорган-2 через отводящий канал. Также каскадную систему будут питать воды из затопленных шахт г. Кентау.&nbsp;</p>
```

И на данный момент я его просто вывожу. Как можно мне преобразовать это в элементы?
Все вывожу в react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: '<p>наливное водохранилище &ndash; часть... </p>' }} />
```